# flutter Run has a problem and doesn't work

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm a newbie learning to write Flutter, but I can't run the app. I don't know what's causing it. I'd like to ask someone who knows how to do it so I can run it.
[image]

I hope it can run programs or apps so that I can continue learning.

Comment: Edit the question and add the stacktrace